# Find $f(x)$ in the following condition

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

$$f(f(x))=x\int_0^xf(t)dt$$

I tried differentiation using chain and lebinitz rules on the lhs and rhs and I ended up with
$$f'(f(x)).f'(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt \ + xf(x)$$
Now I don't know how to solve further from this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where the $z$ comes from?

Comment: @jjagmath I fixed the error

Answer (score 2):

On the left side, you are iterating a function.  On the right side, you are integrating once and multiplying by $x$.  This suggests to me that one look at polynomials, since iterating a polynomial can increase the degree of the polynomial, integrating a polynomial increases its degree, and multiplying by a monomial increases the degree.

In particular, on the right, we integrate once and then multiply by $x$.  If $f$ is a polynomial, we then increase the degree by two.  The only way to iterate a polynomial once and have its degree increase by two is if its degree is already two.

So, Hint: Try $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$ and see what $a$, $b$, and $c$ must be.

I do not know if this yields the only set of solutions, but it certainly yields two distinct solutions.

Comment: The point you made about the function being a polynomial does make sense, but we don't really know that if it'll be a quadratic or of any other order, finding f(f(x)) will get increasingly lengthy with each new degree and this is a practice question from an exam which doesn't really give you much time per question , I feel like it utilizes some tricks involving the rules or integration and functions.

Comment: @Singularity. Sure.  I certainly can't guarantee that this yields all the solutions, but I *think* it's the only possible polynomial solution, for the reasons I outlined in the post.

Comment: Mathematically, $2n=n+2$ under the assumption that $f$ is a polynomial